# How to perform git pull from gitlab repo with 2FA access token using linux terminal?

Tags: linux, git, authentication, gitlab

I had already cloned a few repos from gitlab and then LATER we added two factor authentication on the gitlab repos.

Now I am trying to update my local branch by doing `git pull` like this:

```
sudo git pull
```

but I get an access error like this:

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have created an access token as the gitlab page [describes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) but I am never prompted to use to add my username and access token, it simply says the error message above. How do authenticate my requests?